# How to replace &/or delete rows depending on values in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is such as created using [CMU Book Summary Dataset](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Edbamman/booksummaries.html)

| ID | Book title | Book Author | Genres |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 620 | Animal Farm | George Orwell | ['Science Fiction', 'Novella', 'Speculative fiction', 'Utopian and dystopian fiction', 'Satire', 'Fiction'] |
| 986 | The Plague | Albert Camus | ['Existentialism', 'Fiction', 'Absurdist fiction'] |

The column I am interested is in Genres. I want to delete the rows which doesn't contain any of the following genres and also only keep on genre from the original Genres list.

```
counts_per_genre = {'Science Fiction':0,
                    'Crime Fiction':0,
                    'Non-fiction':0,
                    'Children\'s literature':0,
                    'Fantasy':0,
                    'Mystery':0,
                    'Suspense':0,
                    'Young adult literature':0}
```

What I did was the following (I am totally newbie in this). Create new_class where the new classification of genre will be there. I am having trouble when one of the genre (from count_per_genre) is not in the Genres column....

**How can I delete the rows where the Genres column doesn't have any of the genre listed in the count_per_genre dictionary and also replace the Genres list to only one genre from the same dictionary?**

```
new_class = []
for genre in counts_per_genre.keys():
    for item in book_summary_df['Genre']:
        if genre in item:
            counts_per_genre[genre] += 1
            new_class.append(genre)
```

The wanted result from the above dataframe would be:

| ID | Book title | Book Author | Genres |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 620 | Animal Farm | George Orwell | 'Science Fiction' |

- Please note the line of the book The Plague would be deleted because it doesn't contain any of the genre from count_per_genre.
- Only taking in consideration one match. I am thinking of even changing the counts_per_genre to Fiction and non-fiction only. Something like that.

Comment: What if there are multiple matches. For example it matches `Science Fiction` and `Mystery`. Should all the matches be included in the output?

Comment: No, only one. For example, if the first match is Science Fiction then I would keep Science Fiction only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- key concept is `explode()` embedded list
- then can filter using a mask to wanted rows

```
import json

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""ID  Book title  Book Author Genres
620 Animal Farm George Orwell   ['Science Fiction', 'Novella', 'Speculative fiction', 'Utopian and dystopian fiction', 'Satire', 'Fiction']
986 The Plague  Albert Camus    ['Existentialism', 'Fiction', 'Absurdist fiction']"""), sep="\t")

# needed as read_csv() does not make Genres a list
df.Genres = df.Genres.apply(lambda s: json.loads(s.replace("'","\"")))

counts_per_genre = {'Science Fiction':0,
                    'Crime Fiction':0,
                    'Non-fiction':0,
                    'Children\'s literature':0,
                    'Fantasy':0,
                    'Mystery':0,
                    'Suspense':0,
                    'Young adult literature':0}

# two uses of explode, using mask to include only wanted Genres
df.explode("Genres").loc[df.explode("Genres")["Genres"].isin(counts_per_genre.keys())]
```

|  | ID | Book title | Book Author | Genres |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 620 | Animal Farm | George Orwell | Science Fiction |

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You will get your expected result.

**CODE**

```
for index,value in book_summary_df.iterrows():
    genre = book_summary_df.loc[index,"Genres"]
    matched_gen = []
    for g in genre:
        if not(g in counts_per_genre.keys()):
            break
        else:
            counts_per_genre[g] += 1
            matched_gen.append(g)
    if matched_gen:
        book_summary_df.loc[index,"Genres"]=matched_gen[0]
    else:
        book_summary_df.drop(index,inplace=True)
        
display(book_summary_df)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]